# TcpListener crashing my Windows Form app

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I am trying to make a winform app that will listen for a TCP connection, and then does X if it receives a connection.

The issue that I am having is that when it starts listening the app goes into "not responding"

This is the code I am using:

```
 try
        {
            // set the TcpListener on port 13000
            int port = 13000;
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

            // Start listening for client requests
            server.Start();

            //Enter the listening loop
            while (true)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(@"Waiting for a connection... ");

                server.AcceptTcpClient();

                MessageBox.Show(@"Connected");
               // ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
               // proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
               // proc.FileName = "cmd";
               // proc.Arguments = "/C shutdown -f -r";
               // Process.Start(proc);

            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"SocketException");
        }
```

The strange thing is, is it works just fine as a console app.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: accept() blocks.  You cannot block in a GUI event handler.  Thread it off.

Comment: A form project doesn't need the while loop.  The while loop is called a block and prevent the console application from terminating.  A form project has a block built into the constructor and doesn't need an additional block in your code.

Comment: So i can just remove the while true, and it will run ok?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes.

Comment: It still hangs when i press the button, but it does accept the connection.

Answer (score 1):

As @ThingyWotsit pointed out, `accept()` blocks the thread from execution, which leads to your application hanging (google blocking sockets). However you don't really need to thread it off, there are more options!

1. Threading of. Just run this code block in a separate thread
2. [AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync(v=vs.110).aspx), which is built upon `async/await`. This requires code modifications though
3. `BeginAcceptTcpClient`/`EndAcceptTcpClient`. This is an "old" way of doing stuff, but it deserves to live. An example can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.endaccepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)